# how can one programatically know when video quality changes for android exo video player?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to know, if there is a function or Class which the help of which , I can calculate the bitrate, when video quality changes for android exo video player.

Comment: what exactly does `video quality changes` mean?

Comment: As soon as the Quality of the video, i.e., 144p/240p/360p/480p/720p playing in exo player changes, I want to know or calculate bitrate at that time. In HSL or DASH, the video quality changes adaptively

Comment: I don't think that ExoPlayer is able to change the video quality that way on it's own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got the answer:

***Integer bitrate = player.getVideoFormat().bitrate***

it will return -1 for mp4.

Also:
The ExoPlayer looks for the first source that has a deliveryType of MPEG-DASH, and a profile that is neither urn:hbbtv nor urn:dvb.

If the above is not found, source selection falls back to the first source with a deliveryType of HLS.

If no such source is found, it falls back to the source with a deliveryType of MP4 and a bitrate closest to 256 kBps

So if it returns -1, we can set it to 256kbps.